# Get results from multiple rows with same names

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some tables with various content. What I want to accomplish is to display the lets say 20 latest entries from those tables in a div.

Here is my first table - audio1

```
userID folder title date
```

the two other folders look exactly the same

audio2

```
userID folder title date
```

audio3

```
userID folder title date
```

How can I get the data from all the tables at the same time and echo them one by one to a div ordered by date with PHP?

Comment: Are you having problems with the query, the HTML layout, or the php? Please be specific in your question.

Comment: The html is not the problem, only the query to the database the php is fine as well I just don't know how to fetch information from three tables at once :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL query will be a 3 part [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).  A `UNION` query concatenates results from multiple tables with (usually) similar structures, when a `JOIN` relationship is not needed but rather you just need to return rows from multiple tables.

```
$sql = "SELECT userID, folder, title, date FROM audio1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT userID, folder, title, date FROM audio2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT userID, folder, title, date FROM audio3
  LIMIT 20;";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result) {
  // Fetch results and echo them into a list.
}
```

You will need a column to `ORDER BY`. This is likely to be `date`, but you may have other plans. Add an `ORDER BY` clause before the `LIMIT 20`.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT userID, folder, title, date
    FROM audio1
UNION ALL
SELECT userID, folder, title, date
    FROM audio2
UNION ALL
SELECT userID, folder, title, date
    FROM audio3
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Would the anonymous downvoter care to explain their objection?

Comment: A certain somebody shows up right on time, and everybody gets a downvote... I'm not naming names but the pattern has much precedent in PHP & MySQL :)

Comment: @Michael: So, if I were to note that the downvote occurred at 13:57:41Z, I could, theoretically, look for other activity on this question around that same time? :-)

Comment: That is a nice, scientific way to approach it, yes. :)

Answer (score 1):

it seems that your database setup is wrong and you have to have only one table called 'audio' with a field represents the number you are currently using in the table name.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the union, or you can try a join.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(t1.userID, t2.userID, t3.userID) as userID 
           , t1.folder, t1.title, t1.date
           , t2.folder, t2.title, t2.date  
           , t3.folder, t3.title, t3.date  
FROM table1 t1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.userID = t2.userID)
FULL OUTER JOIN table3 t3 ON (t1.userID = t3.userID)
```

It's a very different beast, so I'd thought I'd give you the option.